# Woocommerce JSON API

Tags: json, rest, woocommerce

I have a problem with woocommerce rest api. I want to create a product with photos via rest api, but it works only without photos.

This snippet of code work:

{
    "regular_price": "21.99",
    "name": "Premium Quality",
    "description": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus",
    "type": "simple"
}

but this doesn't work:

{
    "regular_price": "21.99",
    "images": "[{\"src\":\"https://static01.nyt.com/images/2017/03/17/world/europe/oakImage-1489777706390/oakImage-1489777706390-largeHorizontal375.jpg\",\"position\":0,\"id\":0}]",
    "name": "Premium Quality",
    "description": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus",
    "type": "simple"
}

The JSON is validate. The response from the server is:

{
    "code": "woocommerce_product_invalid_image_id",
    "message": "#0 is an invalid image ID.",
    "data": {
        "status": 400
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/) claims:

> Image ID (attachment ID). In write-mode used to attach pre-existing images.

According to that, you should send this request without the id parameter in your image object. This is because there is no pre-existing image with the id=0, I guess.

Example code taken from the docs:

```
{
  name: 'Premium Quality',
  type: 'simple',
  regular_price: '21.99',
  description: 'Pellentesque habitant morbi...',
  short_descriptienter code hereon: 'Pellentesque ...',
  categories: [
    {
      id: 9
    },
    {
      id: 14
    }
  ],
  images: [
    {
      src: 'http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_front.jpg',
      position: 0
    },
    {
      src: 'http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_back.jpg',
      position: 1
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: I didn't add any ID and posted the product object as above, but still getting **"woocommerce_product_invalid_image_id"** error.

Comment: In my case, the URL did not end with a file extension (.jpg/.png/etc.).  `https://images.g2a.com/images/58x58/0x1x1/f9fffb02f530/590db06e5bafe38c581a220f` was considered invalid. I created a proxy URL that has .jpg/.png with it to solve the issue.

Comment: @Earlee i have same problem how do i create a proxy url?

Comment: i lost the code, but maybe you can search about it. using htaccess, i rewrite `http://myproxy.domain.com/f9fffb02f530/590db06e5bafe38c581a220f.jpg` to index.php in which index.php wgets the image and then displays the image

Comment: @PrinceHamza https://stackoverflow.com/a/72687571 might help