# Woocommerce API thinking image SRC is a different type of file, not a JPG

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

Example:

```
  ["images"]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["src"]=>
      string(112) "https://nz.tradevine.com/BlobStorage/GetFullPhoto?photoID=3783754511503592459&organisationID=3468490059683634443"
      ["position"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
```

The image is https://nz.tradevine.com/BlobStorage/GetFullPhoto?photoID=3783754511503592459&organisationID=3468490059683634443

I get an error: "Error: Invalid image: Sorry, you are not allowed to upload this file type. [woocommerce_api_product_image_upload_error]

I change WP_config file to allow any type of file upload.

define('ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true);

it trys to upload a file called: GetFullPhoto
no .jpg

and it does not work.

This ust to work fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is that realy a file ? The url returns nothing so how to upload nothing ?

Comment: sorry try now @MartinMirchev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the url doesn't include a file extension in it's name, Wordpress treats it as a file with no extension thus failing the `wp_check_filetype_and_ext` test.

You can add a filter to add `.jpg` to the end of a filename if it has no extension and is in fact a jpeg like so

```
add_filter('wp_handle_sideload_prefilter', 'add_jpg_if_no_extension');

function add_jpg_if_no_extension($file){
    if(!pathinfo($file['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION) && mime_content_type($file['tmp_name']) == 'image/jpeg'){
        $file['name'] .= '.jpg';
    }
    return $file;
}
```

**EDIT:**
A more complete solution to work for all image types

```
add_filter('wp_handle_sideload_prefilter', 'add_extension_if_none_exists');

function add_extension_if_none_exists($file){
    if ( pathinfo( $file['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) ) {
        return $file;
    }
    $real_mime = wp_get_image_mime( $file['tmp_name'] );
    $mime_to_ext = apply_filters(
        'getimagesize_mimes_to_exts',
        array(
            'image/jpeg' => 'jpg',
            'image/png'  => 'png',
            'image/gif'  => 'gif',
            'image/bmp'  => 'bmp',
            'image/tiff' => 'tif',
            'image/webp' => 'webp',
        )
    );
    if ( ! empty( $mime_to_ext[ $real_mime ] ) ) {
        $file['name'] .= '.' . $mime_to_ext[ $real_mime ];
    }
    return $file;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thx where do I add this filter?

Comment: You can add it in functions.php in your active theme, preferably a child-theme. Or you can use a [code snippets plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/)

Comment: Thx Moshe, when im doing the api post do I have to call it some how or will it automatically do it?

Comment: It will do it automatically

Answer (score 0):

WordPress determines the image type from filename and the image doesn't have an extension, so you will need to get the image extension using `mime_content_type`, update the image filename with that extension for saving and set the image mime-type and image extension array at filetype check hook

```
add_filter(
    'wp_check_filetype_and_ext',
    function( $filetype_and_ext, $file, $filename, $mimes, $real_mime ) {
        $filename_ext = pathinfo( $filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
        if ( false === $filetype_and_ext['ext'] && false === $filetype_and_ext['type'] && empty( $filename_ext ) && ! empty( $file ) ) {
            $file_mime = @mime_content_type( $file );
            $file_ext  = mime_to_ext( $file_mime );
            if ( in_array( $file_mime, array_values( $mimes ) ) && $file_ext ) {
                $filetype_and_ext['ext']             = $file_ext;
                $filetype_and_ext['type']            = $file_mime;
                $filetype_and_ext['proper_filename'] = $filename . '.' . $file_ext;
            }
        }
        return $filetype_and_ext;
    },
    1000,
    5
);


function mime_to_ext( $mime ) {
    $mimes_to_ext = apply_filters(
        'getimagesize_mimes_to_exts',
        array(
            'image/jpeg' => 'jpg',
            'image/png'  => 'png',
            'image/gif'  => 'gif',
            'image/bmp'  => 'bmp',
            'image/tiff' => 'tif',
            'image/webp' => 'webp',
        )
    );
    if ( ! empty( $mimes_to_ext[ $mime ] ) ) {
        return $mimes_to_ext[ $mime ];
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Tested this, but still doesn't work

Comment: Oh, It's a rest request. It has a different filter hook. The answer is updated. @MosheGross